# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rubygems, mongoid

Here are logs

```
umair-2:game-minion umairejaz$ rails c
/Users/umairejaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/Users/umairejaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:136: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.7)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > u = User.new
=> #<User _id: 4e53f783713931a571000001, _type: nil, username: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, email: nil, password: nil, password_salt: nil, password_hash: nil, profile_picture: nil, facebook_id: nil, facebook_enabled: nil, facebook_access_token: nil, twitter_id: nil, twitter_enabled: nil, twitter_access_token: nil, twitter_access_secret: nil, points: nil, remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > u.username = "umair"
=> "umair" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > u.save(false)
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass
from /Users/umairejaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/mongoid-2.1.9/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations.rb:143:in `validating?'
from /Users/umairejaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/mongoid-2.1.9/lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:23:in `block in prepare'
from /Users/umairejaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/mongoid-2.1.9/lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:22:in `tap'
from /Users/umairejaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/mongoid-2.1.9/lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:22:in `prepare'
from /Users/umairejaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/mongoid-2.1.9/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/insert.rb:26:in `persist'
from /Users/umairejaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/mongoid-2.1.9/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:44:in `insert'
from /Users/umairejaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/mongoid-2.1.9/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:142:in `upsert'
from (irb):3
from /Users/umairejaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /Users/umairejaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/umairejaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :004 >
```

I am getting this above response when I try to save some object. Follwoing are my gem versions of mongoid and mongo , what I think is its an issue of mongoid.yml but not sure as my yml is perfectly fine

Using bson (1.3.1) 
Using bson_ext (1.3.1) 
Using mongo (1.3.1) 
Installing mongoid (2.1.9)

mongoid.yml

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: gm_development

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: gm_test
production:
  host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
  uri: mongodb://username:password@staff.mongohq.com:10029/appid
```

Please let me know if you find anything wrong in this

Comment: What is the definition of the User class?

Comment: try `save(:validate=> false)`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

try:

```
u.save(:validate=> false)
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the underlying problem does it?  Sticking you head in the sand is just going to pop this problem up elsewhere

Comment: @Bill Leeper: The OP tried to skip validations before already, but used the old syntax `u.save(false)`. The error message appears because of a syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

I was posting my object and getting the error in Rails 3.0:

> undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass

but it works find now after I changed my code from:

```
save(false)
```

to:

```
save(:validate=> false)
```

Comment: How does this answer add new information besides the accepted?